# What is {ts '2013-04-02 00:00:00'}?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports-2008

when i analyzing running T-SQL I found a query that have **{ts** '2013-04-02 00:00:00'} in where clause. 
i was so curious about this and tried to find the source. 
It was executed by a CrystalReport Report.

here is the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM    [Table] B
WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR, [AddedDateTime], 111) 
        BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, {ts '2013-03-31 00:00:00'}, 111)
        AND     CONVERT(VARCHAR, {ts '2013-04-02 00:00:00'}, 111)
```

Can anyone tel me what is it and where we can use it?

Comment: i dont have any problem with it, i just wanted to know what is it and where we can use it

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's an [ODBC literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms712360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) escape sequence

> ODBC defines escape sequences for date, time, and timestamp literals. The syntax of these escape sequences is as follows:

```
{ts 'value'}
```

---

> where we can use it?

Anywhere where a `datetime` value is expected. ("timestamp" is SQL Standard vernacular for what SQL Server calls `datetime`).

Comment: To complete the picture: JDBC uses the same escape sequences: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/statement.html#1006519