# Why would "WHERE `DATE` >={ts '2013-12-01 00:00:00'}" produce a different result to "WHERE `DATE` >='2013-12-01 00:00:00'"?

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

As title says - why would the first query (generated automatically by Crystal Reports) above produce a different result (unreliably - the first query gives different results depending on when I run it - the database is not being modified) to the second query above? Going by this reference guide: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html, the output should be the same.

Can anyone offer any advice? Note I am using MySQL version 5.6.15, and this problem only started to occur when we upgraded

Comment: How do the results differ?

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759458/what-is-ts-2013-04-02-000000)

Comment: Results are missing. There are 112 results using the first where clause, and 172 results using the second.

Comment: Can you identify the difference between the two?  Perhaps the 172 record includes 2013-12-01 dates and the other includes dates prior to 2013-12-01.

Comment: This is the very first thing I checked. Unfortunately, it is a mix of dates that are missed.