# Conversion of C# datetime to sql server datetime is throwing an error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

In C# a DateTime property with value `{27-01-2017 12.00.00 AM}` is being passed in a data table to a procedure with an UTT parameter. UTT also has the same datatype datetime. I am using the generic method provided below. I cannot explicitly convert data type.

> Error : The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The data for table-valued parameter
>   @UttParameter doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.
>   SQL Server error is: 242, state: 3
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> items, bool usePropertyMappingName = false)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = null;

        if (items != null)
        {
            using (dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name))
            {
                dataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                // Get all the properties.
                PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
                {
                    string columnName = prop.Name;

                    if (usePropertyMappingName)
                    {
                        var mappingAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PropertyMappingAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as PropertyMappingAttribute;

                        if (mappingAttribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mappingAttribute.Name))
                        {
                            columnName = mappingAttribute.Name;
                        }
                    }

                    // Setting column names as Property names.
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, prop.PropertyType);
                }

                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    var values = new object[props.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // Inserting property values to data table rows.
                        values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                    }

                    dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
                }
            }
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: You're not passing it as a **datetime**, you're passing it as a **string**. You need to post the code that configures the parameter values in C#, including that parameter and its type. If you had passed it as a **datetime** then there would be no conversion so the very fact that you have a conversion error means you're not really doing what you think or say you're doing.

Comment: Are the region settings same in SQL server and your server/machine?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, There is a List<Class1>, Class1 has many properties among which datetime is one of the property. There is a generic method which converts a list of items into a data table. There is no explicit data type conversion happening.

Comment: @Vijayakrishna, It is same.

Comment: *There is a generic method which converts a list of items into a data table*: Show the code, at least the part dealing with datetime values...

Comment: @Shnugo , I have now provided generic code which converts the list into datatable. I cannot modify dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name); to dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType); Because it's a generic method. Nullable properties can not be set. {"DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>."}

Comment: This

`{27-01-2017 12.00.00 AM}`

is a rather odd format.

If you are trying to write an [ODBC timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759458/what-is-ts-2013-04-02-000000), the format would be

`{ts '2017-01-27 00:00:00'}`

Where did you get that string from?  Can you post the c# code that sends it to the database?

Comment: C# code has a list of properties among which has DateTime is the one. While converting the list to data table, it is implicitly converting DateTime to String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code - as it is now - will **transfer any value on string level**. This is a **really bad approach**. The implicit conversions taking place are highly depending on your system's settings (language and culture). The worst part is: This might work all great on your machine while you are testing it, but on a customer's system it breaks with strange messages. Happy Debugging :-(

Change your code like this

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props) {
    // Setting column names as Property names.
    if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
    else
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
}
```

This will add the column - even if this is a nullable type - with the correct data type.

**credits:** [This answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5644623/5089204)

### UPDATE Even simpler

(thx to Yves M. in a comment below the linked answer)

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props) {
    // Setting column names as Property names.
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
}
```

Comment: dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType); This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotation marks

> "@UttParameter"

```
@UttParameter
```

Comment: This is not at all a problem. Actual problem is with the datatype which is being implicitly converted from datetime to string.

Answer (score 1):

You are using InvariantCulture as DataTable locale. Invariant culture expects Date to be in yyyy-MM-dd format.

Comment: The problem was with the type conversion. I had to specify the type as `DateTime` while creating the data table. Now the generic method has been modified to handle nullable datatypes. As in the comment you asked, I thought you were asking about timezone of database server and application server. Later I noticed that someone had changed the date format of database server.