# Message 102 Level 15 error SQL Server: Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am facing an error while running a SQL query.

The error I am receiving is:

> *(102, b"Incorrect syntax near '2020-01-31 00:00:00'.DB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages
>   from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral
>   SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error
>   message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages
>   from the SQL Server\n")*

Since the query is lengthy, I am putting only part of the query where the error is being shown:

```
T1.submit_date < ts '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
```

If need be, I will edit and put the entire query.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what is ts here ?

Comment: This is SQL Server (Microsoft SQL, MS SQL) error message, not MySQL message. Compare one more time letter-by-letter: `MS SQL` and `MySQL`.

Comment: Hi Red. ts is timestamp, an ODBC literal escape sequence. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759458/what-is-ts-2013-04-02-000000

Comment: Hi Akina. It is MySQL that I am using in the backend. I am unclear on a thing. Are you suggesting that I should change the title of my question and the tags? I think the server is throwing an error because of something wrong in the query.

Comment: If your employer told you to use [MySQL by  Oracle Corporation](https://www.mysql.com/) you must have made something wrong because the error message you're getting comes from [SQL Server by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).

Comment: Oh really sorry guys. I am new to databases and didn't know that these two are two different technologies themselves. { insert embarrassed emoji here }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct format for [ODBC escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/date-time-and-timestamp-escape-sequences?view=sql-server-ver15). It should be wrapped in `{}`

```
where T1.submit_date < {ts '2020-01-31 00:00:00'}
```

Comment: Upon changing the code to this, I get another error: _Keyerror at "ts '2020-01-31 00"_

Comment: That isn't a database error. Probably you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo